# Laravel setting default parameters for route resource

Tags: laravel, routes

I have been reading the documentation about Laravel routes.
I like the Route::resource approach, less code is pretty nice. But when I read further it a RESTfull approach? It's still a good thing to use it when I am not worried about this RESTfull thingy?

The actual question: I am this far right now.
I use packages shop, blog, etc. I assign routes seperatly for each package.
I could do this:

```
Route::resource('dashboard/{taxonomy}', 'Post\AdminController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'page-list',
        'store' => 'page-store',
        // etc...
    ]
])->where('taxonmy', 'page');
```

but now I use:

```
Route::resource('dashboard/page', 'Post\AdminController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'page-list',
        'store' => 'page-store',
        // etc...
    ]
]); // I would like to add ->defaults('taxonomy', 'page'); because all methods need this parameter
```

I know the names parameters work because the docs tell me so.
The docs are not telling me if it's possible to add default parameters.
I need the parameter "slug" to default to false for the route dashboard/page.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

What I want to achieve is a default taxonomy for all routes, and a slug parameter for a specific route.
For example, (how I did routes before):

```
Route::get('dashboard/page/new', [
    'as'    => 'page-new',
    'uses'  => 'Post\AdminController@create'
])->defaults('slug', false)
->defaults('taxonomy', 'page');
```

Comment: You can specify a default value for a parameter when getting the value from the request: `request()->input('taxonomy', 'page')`. If you don't want to repeat the default value, add a constant for it in your base controller or wrap the whole parameter retrieval into its own method in the base controller (or a trait if that suits you more).

Comment: You sure about that? I don't see an edit...

Comment: @Namoshek refresh, I just saved it, oh wait... I might figure it out in the construct.... like you said... if the taonomy is page then slug is false...

Comment: Are we talking about GET parameters or parts of the URL like `page-list/{slug}`?